# Changing Data Class From Live Data

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a BaseViewModel that basically has the function to get the user data like so:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel(
    private val repository: BaseRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private var _userResponse: MutableLiveData<Resource<UserResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
    val userResponse: LiveData<Resource<UserResponse>> get() = _userResponse
    
    fun getUserData() = viewModelScope.launch {
        _userResponse.value = Resource.Loading
        _userResponse.value = repository.getLoggedInUserData()
    }
}
```

In my Fragment, I access this data by just calling viewModel.getUserData(). This works. However, I'd like to now be able to edit the data. For example, the data class of UserResponse looks like this:

```
data class UserResponse(
    var id: Int,
    var username: String,
    var email: String
)
```

In other fragments, I'd like to edit username and email for example. How do I do access the UserResponse object and edit it? Is this a good way of doing things? The `getUserData` should be accessed everywhere and that is why I'm including it in the abstract BaseViewModel. Whenever the UserResponse is null, I do the following check:

```
if (viewModel.userResponse.value == null) {
    viewModel.getUserData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to edit the data in `userResponse`, really what you're talking about is changing the *value* it holds, right? The best way to do that is through the `ViewModel` itself:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel(
    private val repository: BaseRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private var _userResponse: MutableLiveData<Resource<UserResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
    val userResponse: LiveData<Resource<UserResponse>> get() = _userResponse

    fun setUserResponse(response: UserResponse) {
        _userResponse.value = response
    }

    ...
}
```

This has a few advantages - first, the view model is responsible for holding and managing the data, and provides an interface for reading, observing, and updating it. Rather than having lots of places where the data is manipulated, those places just call this one function instead. That makes it a lot easier to change things later, if you need to - the code that calls the function might not need to change at all!

This also means that you can expand the update logic more easily, since it's all centralised in the VM. Need to write the new value to a `SavedStateHandle`, so it's not lost if the app goes to the background? Just throw that in the update function. Maybe persist it to a database? Throw that in. None of the callers need to know what's happening in there

The other advantage is you're *actually setting a new value on the `LiveData`*, which means your update behaviour is consistent and predictable. If the user response changes (either a whole new one, or a change to the current one) then everything `observe`ing that `LiveData` sees the update, and can decide what to do with it. It's less brittle than this idea that one change to the current response is "new" and another change is "an update" and observers will only care about one of those and don't need to be notified of the other. Consistency in how changes are handled will avoid bugs being introduced later, and just make it easier to reason about what's going on

---

There's nothing *stopping* you from updating the properties of the object held in `userResponse`, just like there's nothing stopping you from holding a `List` in a `LiveData`, and adding elements to that list. Everything with a reference to that object will see the new data, *but only if they look at it*. The point of `LiveData` and the observer pattern is to *push* updates to observers, so they can *react* to changes (like, say, updating text displayed in a UI). If you change one of the `var`s in that data class, how are you going to make sure everything that needs to see those changes definitely sees them? How can you ensure that will always happen, as the app gets developed, possibly by other people? The observer pattern is about simplifying that logic - update happens, observers are notified, the end

If you **are** going to do things this way, then I'd still recommend putting an update function in your VM, and let *that* update the `var`s. You get the same benefits - centralising the logic, enabling things like persistence if it ever becomes necessary, etc. It could be as simple as

```
    fun setUserResponse(response: UserResponse) {
        _userResponse.value?.run {
            id = response.id
            username = response.username
            email = response.email
        }
    }
```

and if you *do* decide to go with the full observer pattern for all changes later, everything is already calling the function the right way, no need for changes there. Or you could just make separate `updateEmail(email: String)` etc functions, whatever you want to do. But putting all that logic in the VM is a good idea, it's kinda what it's there for

Oh and you access that object through `userResponse.value` if you want to poke at it - but like I said, better to do that inside a function in the VM, keep that implementation detail, null-safety etc in one place, so callers don't need to mess with it

Comment: I have UserResponse set like so Resource<UserResponse> where Resource is a sealed data class. How do I go about accessing UserResponse like so?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to update `userResponse` you should change/edit `_userResponse` so that your `userResponse` we'll give you the updated data.

it should be something like this

```
_userResponse.value = Resource<UserResponse>()
```

Comment: How would I go about that? _userResponse.Value.username = "whatever" for example doesn't work

Comment: you can do something like this _userResponse.value = Resource<UserResponse>()

Comment: But I don't want to update the whole object. Just part of it

Comment: Copy the old data and update with new name etc.  then pass it to _userResponse

Comment: But why can't the old object update?

Comment: MutableStateFlow for that it will help to do exactly what you want.